# Redirect woocommerce single-product page

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

My question conserns the Woocommerce plugin.

As you know we can create a custom **single-page.php** within our theme provided it is inside woocommerce subfolder.

What I need is the ability to have the **single-product.php** file inside my plugin.

I have tried a lot of ways and it works for other pages, for example I can redirect **single-product/title.php** to another page but I have had no luck redirect **single-product.php**.

I understand I probably can redirect it through httaccess file but what I need is redirecting the file through a plugin.

It seems that woocommerce specifies the template file after **template_include** hook.

So far I managed to use **woocommerce_locate_template** filter to redirect to some files but for **single-product.php** there seems to be a complete different story.

Any idea how I can have my own single-product.php inside my  custom plugin?

UPDATE: I tried the solution given by one of the answer as follow:

```
add_filter('single_template', 'my_custom_template');
function my_custom_template($single) {
    global $post;
    if ( $post->post_type == 'product' ) {
        echo 'test';// So its here
        return plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ).'woocommerce/single-product.php';
    }
    return $single;
}
```

The single-product page still goes to the default woocommerce template pages.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom Post Type Templates from Plugin Folder?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/17385/custom-post-type-templates-from-plugin-folder)

Comment: `/woocommerce/single-page.php` and all other files within `/woocommerce/` (inside theme folder) work with WooCommerce logic. `/single-product.php` is default WordPress logic (aka [template hierarchy](https://wphierarchy.com/)). So the solution from the linked answer should work here as well

Comment: I have tried that answer and edited my question to reflect the result, it didn't work. As you see this is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per this post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43621049/woocommerce-multiple-single-product-templates-using-single-product-php-to-redire) I would update your code to look like this:

```
function so_43621049_template_include( $template ) {
  if ( is_singular('product') ) {
    $template = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ).'woocommerce/single-product.php';
  } 
  return $template;
}
add_filter( 'template_include', 'so_43621049_template_include', 20 );
```

I haven't had a chance to test this but I believe it will work.

Comment: template_include hook doesn't work for single-product.php. The post mentioned uses get_stylesheet_directory()  not plugin_dir_url. For redirecting to woocommerce folder inside a theme we don't need a filter.

Comment: @agahi, `template_include` does work. If it doesn't for you, try lowering the priority (i.e. use a *greater* number) - `add_filter( 'template_include', 'your_function', 20 )`. And as for the `$template`, you can simply set it to the proper file path - `$template = 'path/to/your/custom-single-product.php'`

Comment: Thanks Sally CJ.  I'll mark Fence04's as answer but should change plugin_dir_url to plugin_dir_path and add a proirity to the filter.

Comment: Thanks @SallyCJ I was coming on after testing last night to make exactly that change.

Comment: You're welcome @agahi and Fencer04 :)