# Override WooCommerce files from plugin

Tags: plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic

I want to display my custom template for Single Product i.e. `single-product.php`

For WordPress native templates, we can use `add_filter( 'single_template', 'custom_single_tmpl' );` and a callback function looks like this:

```
    public function custom_single_tmpl( $tempalte ) {
       return PLUG_DIR_PATH . '/templates/custom-single.php';
    }
```

Is there any way to **override** WooCommerce template files like that?

**Edit:**
I want to override Header and Footer as well, not only a single product content (same way as WordPress above `add_filter` does).

Comment: Can anyone explain why this question gets downvoted? Or comments removed on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use my answer from this post to change the template: [Redirect woocommerce single-product page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/319763/redirect-woocommerce-single-product-page/319769)

Then you could use the following functions in your functions.php file to change the header and footer only on that template:

```
function themeslug_footer_hook( $name ) {
    if ( get_page_template() == "Your Page Template"  ) { 
        <!-- New Footer Content -->
    }
}
add_action( 'get_footer', 'themeslug_footer_hook' );

function themeslug_header_hook( $name ) {
    if ( get_page_template() == "Your Page Template"  ) { 
        <!-- New Header Content -->
    }
}
add_action( 'get_header', 'themeslug_header_hook' );
```

Comment: Mate, **FROM PLUGIN** not from the theme. What's wrong with my question, nobody understands it...

Comment: The function names don't matter. This will work in a plugin without an issue.