# Warning , Use of undefined constant PLUGIN_PATH?

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, templates

I having a warning in my error log

> Use of undefined constant PLUGIN_PATH - assumed 'PLUGIN_PATH' (this
>   will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)

When I googled it I couldn't find the answer but seems a lot of websites are showing up this warning publically?

```
add_filter('single_template', 'my_custom_template');

function my_custom_template($single) {

    global $post;

    /* Checks for single template by post type */
    if ( $post->post_type == 'POST TYPE NAME' ) {
        if ( file_exists( PLUGIN_PATH . '/Custom_File.php' ) ) {
            return PLUGIN_PATH . '/Custom_File.php';
        }
    }

    return $single;

}
```

This was the code that I used: [Custom Post Type Templates from Plugin Folder?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/17385/custom-post-type-templates-from-plugin-folder)

any fix?

Comment: Use [plugin_dir_path()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/plugin_dir_path/) instead of `PLUGIN_PATH`  as mentioned in the commentary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is self explanatory: `PLUGIN_PATH` is not defined anywhere.

It is not one of WordPress' default constants (which are listed [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Determining_Plugin_and_Content_Directories), and all start with `WP_`). In the context of the code you've copied, it's apparent that it was either supposed to be replaced with the path to your plugin (in which case using a constant in the example code was a bad idea), or it used to exist (the answer is 8 years old). This is mentioned in the comments on your own link.

To get the path to a plugin file (these days at least), you need to use [`plugin_dir_path()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/plugin_dir_path/):

```
if ( file_exists( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'Custom_File.php' ) ) {
    return plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'Custom_File.php';
}
```

Just be aware that `plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ )` returns the path to the current file, so if the file containing this code is in a subfolder of your plugin you need to account for that.

Comment: Thanks you. But `PLUGIN_PATH` seems to work though it gives the warning?

Comment: If it’s throwing that specific error then it’s impossible for it to work unless your file is inside a directory literally called `/PLUGIN_PATH/`. Are you sure you don’t have an identical or similar template in your theme?

Comment: Sorry. The problem was with subfolder. The file was inside another folder. The check resulted in bool false so it was returning to the default