# Single Template for Custom Post Type stops working after Wordpress 5.4 update

Tags: custom-post-types, updates

Has anyone else had trouble with single custom post type templates after Wordpress 5.4 update? Mine were fine and then just stopped after update.

Comment: They're fine here, can you be more specific? This isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site, so we need to be able to write an answer to the question that's true for all people, you need to ask a specific question that can be answered

Answer (score 1):

Nothing changed in WP 5.4 regarding singular post types. The template hierarchy remains the same.

E.g for a post type named `book` WP will try to load the first file it finds in this list:

- `{selected-custom-template}.php`
- `single-book-{slug}.php`
- `single-book.php`
- `single.php`
- `singular.php`
- `index.php`

Your problems cause is elsewhere, if you've followed the standard approach to templates you should see no difference.

Comment: Well, that's what's weird. It was working fine. The slug is "programs" and the single page is "single-programs.php." After the update it stopped.

Comment: Also, tried updating the permalinks, nothing. Tried deactivating and reactivating the plugin, nothing. Tried the same with the theme. Nothing.

Comment: I can't debug code I can't see, and your question asked if anything changed, it didn't. If my answer answers your question can you mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 1):

So, I got things working. The single-{postypes} were part of a plugin. These were working fine but stopped after the update. I had to go and add the following filter and then everything started working again.

So, not sure about the root cause but this did work.

I found the answer here: [Custom Post Type Templates from Plugin Folder?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/17385/custom-post-type-templates-from-plugin-folder)

```
function load_single_template( $template ) {
    global $post;

    if ( 'schedule-items' === $post->post_type && locate_template( array( 'single-schedule-items.php' ) ) !== $template ) {
        return plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'scheduler/single-schedule-items.php';
    }

    if ( 'programs' === $post->post_type && locate_template( array( 'single-programs.php' ) ) !== $template ) {
        return plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'programs/single-programs.php';
    }

    if ( 'faculty-members' === $post->post_type && locate_template( array( 'single-faculty-members.php' ) ) !== $template ) {
        return plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'faculty/single-faculty-members.php';
    }

    return $template;
}

add_filter( 'single_template', 'load_single_template' );
```